# Can you deploy transaction security policies

Tags: security, shield

Is it possible to deploy Transaction Security Policies using change sets? These policies are part of the Salesforce Shield Event Monitoring product. Each policy is required to have a user in the "Recipient" and "Execute Policy As" fields. But when you try to deploy from one org to the other I get the error message `In field: Username - no User named [myUserName] found`. Since usernames are unique per Salesforce org I will always get this message. Anyone else run into this issue?

The workaround is to recreate all the transaction security policies manually in each org.

Comment: How are you deploying? Changesets? Metadata API? This issue arises with dashboards too - you'll have to change the User to a User in your destination org - impossible to do declaratively, but possible to do if your pushing via metadata api.

Comment: I am using change sets (I updated my question so its clear). Thanks for suggesting the metadata api workaround!